# Python - Converting 3D numpy array to 2D

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D matrix like this:

```
array([[[ 0,  1],
      [ 2,  3]],

      [[ 4,  5],
      [ 6,  7]],

      [[ 8,  9],
      [10, 11]],

      [[12, 13],
      [14, 15]]])
```

and would like to stack them in a grid format, ending up with:

```
 array([[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11],
        [12, 13],
        [14, 15]])
```

Currently, I'm using numpy as a library.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you to visit this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)
also for this case would work np.reshape((-1,2))

Comment: This works nicely! the exactly syntax would be `arr.reshape((-1, 2))`, and the link seems to be wrong, reshape is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html. @GrozaiL, but this (-1, 2) feels like magic for me, could you explain how it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `numpy.reshape()` allows you to do reshaping in multiple ways.

It usually unravels the array row by row and then reshapes to the way you want it.

If you want it to unravel the array in column order you need to use the argument `order='F'`

Let's say the array is `a`.
For the case above, you have a `(4, 2, 2) ndarray`

`numpy.reshape(a, (8, 2))` will work.

**In the general case of a `(l, m, n) ndarray:`**

`numpy.reshape(a, (l*m, n))` should be used.

Or, `numpy.reshape(a, (a.shape[0]*a.shape[1], a.shape[2]))` should be used.

For more info [numpy.reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)